# delimit data on columns to new columns python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delimit some data from a txt file into a dataframe, but when I open this file via pandas module, the data just has 1 column. I want to delimit this data into 17 columns. The data from txt file look like:

[image]

In python, I have the following code using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
count=1
nama = 'Data/'+'%d.txt'%(count)
df = pd.read_table(nama,sep = '\t',header=None)
df_head1=df
df_sta=df
data_sta=df_sta.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5])
print(data_sta)
```

I need to split into columns like sta, date, time, Latitude, Longitude, and sta time. If i delimit in excel,the data i want look like :
[The data i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziyxu.png)

ps: i have used delim_whitespace=True, but that's not running and the message is :
    pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 6, saw 4

Comment: pd.read_csv(inputfile, skiprows=howmanyrowstoskip, sep=delimiter,nrows=howmanyrowstoreadin)

Comment: `skiprows` can be used here

Comment: this is also useful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post subset of your data in your question, and what you expect your output to look like so we can properly help you. It is hard to replicate from an picture, and it is not completely clear what you are asking.

Comment: you can read your file as a tab delimiter which it looks like using '/t' as seperator, if it doesnot work use delim_whitespace=True while reading the file. remember to use skiprows and start reading right where your header column starts.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, sorry i forget to tell this, i have used delim_whitespace=True, but that's not running and the message is : pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 6, saw 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if delimit by tab '\t' doesn't work use :

```
df = pd.read_table(filename,delim_whitespace=True,skiprows = 'number_of_rows_before_the_headers_start')
```

this is similar to using `delimiter=r"\s+"` but i feel the above method is faster than the regex.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, sorry i forget to tell this, i have used delim_whitespace=True, but that's not running and the message is : pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 6, saw 4